# Use fmt specifier in struct tag

Tags: go

Is it possible to use fmt specifier or something like that in the struct tag in Golang, e.g.

```golang
type MyReqest struct {
    category string fmt.Sprintf(`json:"category" binding:"required,oneof=%s"`, strings.Join(options, " "))
}
```

This is not working but I want to know if Golang support such a feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible. Closest possible thing is to use `go generate` code generator to generate the entire struct including tags. That will be done during build time and not runtime.

See: https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Generate_Go_files_by_processing_source and https://go.dev/blog/generate .

If you need to do this in runtime you can probably use [`reflect.StructOf`](https://pkg.go.dev/reflect#StructOf) to define the entire struct with tags in runtime.